# Unable to understand $EIP changes with Buffer Overflow

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, debugging, gcc

I am learning Buffer Overflow, so the question might seem silly but here it is.
I started with this very simple buggy program

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char buf[128];
  printf("You entered value %s\n", argv[1]);
  strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
  printf("%s\n", buf);
  printf("Program is exitting normally!!\n\n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Now when I turn gdb on and run it with a simple set of input `HElooooooooooooooooooooooooo`, it works normally with eip set to very next instruction after `strcpy` function.

```
0x565555ce <+81>:   call   0x56555400 <strcpy@plt>
0x565555d3 <+86>:   add    $0x10,%esp
0x565555d6 <+89>:   sub    $0xc,%esp
0x565555d9 <+92>:   lea    -0x98(%ebp),%eax
```

`$eip` contains `0x565555d3` and I can see Little Endian version of my input smoothly. Things work fine.

```
(gdb) x/40x $esp
0xffffd260: 0xffffd270  0xffffd566  0xf7ffdaf8  0x56555598
0xffffd270: 0x6f6c4548  0x6f6f6f6f  0x6f6f6f6f  0x6f6f6f6f
0xffffd280: 0x6f6f6f6f  0x6f6f6f6f  0x6f6f6f6f  0x00000000
0xffffd290: 0x00000000  0x00000001  0xf7ffd940  0x000000c2
```

But when I provide it with `1000 A's`. I expect to see corrupted area around `$esp` and an expected corrupted value of `$eip` something like `0x41414141` but neither of it happens.

After corruption, area around `$esp` looks pretty normal

```
(gdb) x/40x $esp
0xffffd27c: 0x565555d3  0xffffd290  0x00000000  0xf7ffdaf8
0xffffd28c: 0x56555598  0x00000000  0xf7fdff8b  0x5655523c
0xffffd29c: 0xffffd2fc  0xf7ffda9c  0x00000001  0xf7fcf410
0xffffd2ac: 0x00000001  0x00000000  0x00000001  0xf7ffd940
0xffffd2bc: 0x000000c2  0x00000000  0x00ca0000  0x00000000
0xffffd2cc: 0xf7ffd000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xffffd2dc: 0xa7a40500  0x00000009  0xffffd56c  0xf7e03fa9
0xffffd2ec: 0xf7fac748  0xf7fa9000  0xf7fa9000  0x00000000
```

and `$eip` becomes `0xf7e62238` which obviously is not the right value of the next instruction after `strcpy` so it means something has changed it.

Now I am unable to find two things.

1. Where are all `A`'s?
2. How `$eip` has changed like that?

I am using following command to disable protection plus I have changed `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` to 0. gcc version is `7.3.0`.

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -zexecstack -m32 -o overflow overflow.c
```

Is there something preventing overflow which I have missed or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Switch "-g" , when you compile your c File with gcc.

Or there is something with the Security Features, that prevent your Code.

Did you try to break your Code ?

E.g.

> "break main" and "break 5" and "break 8"
>
> on "break 8" you might try to examine the buffer "x/s buf" or "x/40x buf" ?

Before ending the Program you should see a message that it can't access Address 0x41414141. After continuing you should see an error message.

Comment: Yeah I have inserted breakpoints but when I try to see the value of buf, it says `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.` I use again this command `file ./overflow` but it says `Reading symbols from ./overflow...(no debugging symbols found)...done.` I am not adding any breakpoints before starting gdb, i guess it says this for that reason. But I am unable to look at value of buf

Comment: Also I have searched and these are all the protections I have found so I dont know am I missing anything else

Comment: Try to compile your c code like "gcc -g -o overflow overflow.c" , with the -g switch it will load then the Symbols in gdb.

Comment: Yeah i did and now debugging is fine

Answer (score 1):

First, you better try to overflow the saved `eip` of a regular function, not `main()`. It is not really different, but the `main()` function is a bit specific and might give you a distorted view of reality.

Let's try with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(char *msg)
{
  char buf[64];
  printf ("You entered value %s\n", msg);
  strcpy (buf, msg);
  printf ("%s\n", buf);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc > 1)
    foo(argv[1]);

  printf ("Program is exiting normally!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

First, lets compile it:

```
$> gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -m32 -g -o vulnerable vulnerable.c
```

Then, lets start it with `gdb`:

```
$> gdb -q ./vulnerable
Reading symbols from ./vulnerable...done.
(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11db: file vulnerable.c, line 7.
(gdb) r $(python -c 'print("A" * 64)')
Starting program: /tmp/vulnerable $(python -c 'print("A" * 64)')

Breakpoint 1, foo (msg=0xffffd53a 'A' <repeats 64 times>) at vulnerable.c:7
7     printf ("You entered value %s\n", msg);
(gdb)
```

Now, we are just at the point where we can overflow the buffer and overwrite the saved `eip` which is stored on the stack. But, we entered only 64 '`A`' (the size of the buffer), and we need to know how many '`A`' we need to insert to reach the saved `eip` on the stack.

What we will try to do is:

- Get the address of the buffer;
- Get the address of the saved `eip` on the stack;
- Get the difference between these two addresses which should give us the exact size of the padding we need to insert to reach the saved `eip`.

Lets go:

```
(gdb) p &buf
$1 = (char (*)[64]) 0xffffd280

(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffffd2d0:
 eip = 0x565561db in foo (vulnerable.c:7); saved eip = 0x56556249
 called by frame at 0xffffd300
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xffffd2c8, args: msg=0xffffd53a 'A' <repeats 64 times>
 Locals at 0xffffd2c8, Previous frame's sp is 0xffffd2d0
 Saved registers:
  ebx at 0xffffd2c4, ebp at 0xffffd2c8, eip at 0xffffd2cc

(gdb) p 0xffffd2cc-0xffffd280
$3 = 76
```

Now, we know that if we feed the program with 76 characters of padding, we will overwrite the saved `eip` with the next 4 characters (you are in 32-bit here).

Lets try:

```
(gdb) r $(python -c 'print("A" * 76 + "\xde\xad\xbe\xef"[::-1])')
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /tmp/vulnerable $(python -c 'print("A" * 76 + "\xde\xad\xbe\xef"[::-1])')

Breakpoint 1, foo (
    msg=0xffffd52a 'A' <repeats 76 times>, <incomplete sequence \336>)
    at vulnerable.c:7
7     printf ("You entered value %s\n", msg);
(gdb) n
You entered value AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAﾭ�
8     strcpy (buf, msg);
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffffd2c0:
 eip = 0x565561f0 in foo (vulnerable.c:8); saved eip = 0x56556249
 called by frame at 0xffffd2f0
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xffffd2b8, args: 
    msg=0xffffd52a 'A' <repeats 76 times>, <incomplete sequence \336>
 Locals at 0xffffd2b8, Previous frame's sp is 0xffffd2c0
 Saved registers:
  ebx at 0xffffd2b4, ebp at 0xffffd2b8, eip at 0xffffd2bc
(gdb) n
9     printf ("%s\n", buf);
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffffd2c0:
 eip = 0x56556202 in foo (vulnerable.c:9); saved eip = 0xdeadbeef
 called by frame at 0xffffd2c4
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xffffd2b8, args: 
    msg=0xffffd500 "S\340\347Q\217\363\004x(\355\ri686"
 Locals at 0xffffd2b8, Previous frame's sp is 0xffffd2c0
 Saved registers:
  ebx at 0xffffd2b4, ebp at 0xffffd2b8, eip at 0xffffd2bc
```

Now, we have the complete control of the saved `eip` as we just wrote `0xdeadbeef` on it. Thus, we can control the execution once we exit from this `foo()` function.

If you want to look at what you just wrote on the stack, now you can do:

```
(gdb) x /32x $esp
0xffffd270: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd280: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd290: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd2a0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd2b0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0xdeadbeef
0xffffd2c0: 0xffffd500  0xffffd384  0xffffd390  0x5655622b
0xffffd2d0: 0xffffd2f0  0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf7de79a1
0xffffd2e0: 0xf7fa4000  0xf7fa4000  0x00000000  0xf7de79a1
```

As you can see, you find all the 76 '`A`' followed by the `0xdeadbeef`. In fact, this is your buffer `buf`, followed by the saved `ebp` and the saved `eip` that you just rewrote.

A final note about the ASLR and the non-executable stack. These two protections are not playing any role here. They have to be disabled only if you want to execute a shellcode you inject through this overflow. The ASLR render more difficult to write a meaningful address in place of `0xdeadbeef` because the memory context will change all the time. And, the non-executable stack, will just ruin your attempts to execute code on the stack.

If you just want to control the saved `eip`, you only need to disable the stack canaries (`stack-protector` option). The rest will be meaningful only afterward when you will try to use this control to redirect it to some code you own.